# How to programatically replicate a mosaic style as in CardBuilder.Layout.COLUMNS?

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

What are the components required to be able to do that dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think GDK exposes APIs to make a mosaic style.

You can check out Comcast [FreeFlow](https://github.com/Comcast/FreeFlow). It's open source and the example is also available on GitHub. [The artbook example](https://github.com/Comcast/FreeFlow/tree/master/examples/Artbook) will give you a good idea how to use the library. (The example is an phone app but should be easy to modify to a Glass version.)

[image]